# ASP-MVC: How to take an object property from a controller and pass it into view using custom html helper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am struggling to find out how to take an object property from a controller, let's say I want to take the ID of an object being displayed in the view, to be used in a custom HTML Helper that I made. Then how to use this ID to be used as the value of a hidden  html tag in the view.

Here is the html helper:

```
public static IHtmlString AddLink<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, string linkText, string containerElement, string counterElement, string collectionProperty, Type nestedType)
        {
            var ticks = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;
            var nestedObject = Activator.CreateInstance(nestedType);
            var partial = htmlHelper.EditorFor(x => nestedObject).ToHtmlString().JsEncode();
            partial = partial.Replace("id=\\\"nestedObject", "id=\\\"" + collectionProperty + "_" + ticks + "_");
            partial = partial.Replace("name=\\\"nestedObject", "name=\\\"" + collectionProperty + "[" + ticks + "]");
            var js = string.Format("javascript:addNestedForm('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}');return false;", containerElement, counterElement, ticks, partial);
            TagBuilder tb = new TagBuilder("a");
            tb.Attributes.Add("href", "#");
            tb.Attributes.Add("onclick", js);
            tb.InnerHtml = linkText;
            var tag = tb.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(tag);
        }
```

And here is the controller method, which is an edit function of a Product object:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
        {
            //Product product = _db.Products.Find(id);

            Product product = _db.Products
                .Include(i => i.Parts)
                .Where(i => i.Id == id)
                .SingleOrDefault();

            if (product == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            return View(product);
        }
```

And for the view, where I used the html helper function is here:

```
<p>
    @Html.AddLink("Add More Part", "#parts", ".part", "Parts", typeof(percobaan2.Models.Part))
</p>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about adding a extra parameter `string objectId` in your helper extension method and pass the model id to the same.

```
public static IHtmlString AddLink<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper
, string linkText, string containerElement, string counterElement, 
string collectionProperty, Type nestedType, 
string objectId)
{

}
```

Then

```
@Html.AddLink("Add More Part", "#parts", ".part", "Parts",
typeof(percobaan2.Models.Part), 
Convert.ToString(percobaan2.Models.Part.Id))
```

Comment: Wow, lemme try ittt :D

Comment: Wait a minute, I am still repairing some code, so I could not test it right away, but I have a question. We might have passed the parameter. hmm.. do we need to assign the parameter to the value of the html tag we want, or we just leave it like that? Like it will automatically detech the string objectId as the value of the html tag?

Comment: Noooo. You have to code whatever you want. We paid for that only :)

Comment: @AceSupriatna, you need to code like `tb.Attributes.Add("id", objectId);`

Comment: Oh I see :D Sorry I am learning this html helper, so I am doing baby step here. Btw, isn't that should be like tb.Attributes.Add("value", objectId); ? because I want to assign to the html tag value? sorry if I am wrong :S